# SmartCard reader

Tags: dell-latitude, card-reader, smartcard

I have a Dell D620 which has a builtin smart card reader.

How do I read from and write to a smart card using a smartcard reader?
What are the best/free available softwares that I can use?

Any ideas?

Note: I have absolutely no idea whatsoever regarding what and how I can use a smartcard reader; please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Do you know the model of the reader? You should be able to find more information on the manufacturer's website. There may even be software to use with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartCard readers usually have their own custom software. I checked Dell's drivers and [downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&ServiceTag=CCHYJK1&SystemID=lat_e6400&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=&impid=) for your laptop but I did not see anything related to the smartcard reader. Based on the description, it looks like the smartcard reader is intended to be used kinda like a fingerprint reader to allow access based on a [security card](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19277980.aspx). If your machine did not come with the proper software and the Dell software page does not list it, you can see if you can find the model number or manufacturer of the smartcard reader in device manager and download the software from them. If you boot Knoppix and do a `lspci -v`, it should list all PCI devices and you might get more details about your device.

[Here](https://www.usermanuals.tech/d/dell-drac-5-user-guide/part16#153) is additional information.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSC project](http://www.opensc-project.org) has links to software (Linux, Windows) you can use with cryptographic smart cards.

You will need a functioning smart card reader driver, if you're using Windows, you probably have it installed with the Dell software. With Linux, the builtin readers sometimes cause problems because there are no available drivers.

Assuming you have a working smart card reader, the software depends more in the type of cards you want to use rather than the reader. So what kind of smart cards and how would you like to use?